# How to set default option in select with Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to set the "Seleccionar tamaño" option as default but I cant..

```
        <select name="tamano" ng-model="pizza.initial_prize" class="form-control select">
            <option ng-value="0">Seleccionar tamaño</option>
            <option ng-value="pizza.fam">Familiar</option>
            <option ng-value="pizza.med">Mediana</option>
            <option ng-value="pizza.peq">Pequeña</option>
        </select>
```

Can someone explain me how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assign **0** in **pizza.initial_prize**

**Controller**

```
$scope.pizza.initial_prize=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your  `<!-- app.js -->`

```
 $scope.pizza.initial_prize = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ng-init :

```
<select name="tamano" ng-model="pizza.initial_prize" ng-init="pizza.initial_prize= options[0]" class="form-control">
        <option ng-value="0">Seleccionar tamaño</option>
        <option ng-value="pizza.fam">Familiar</option>
        <option ng-value="pizza.med">Mediana</option>
        <option ng-value="pizza.peq">Pequeña</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use selected as follows:

```
<option ng-value="0" selected>Seleccionar tamaño</option>
```